# My widget is rebuilt when toggling visibility where it shouldn't

Tags: flutter, widget, visibility, rebuild

I have a `StatefulWidget` that basically consists on a background widget (an playing video) and foreground HUD `Column` of Widget. The later visibility can be toggled by taping on an `ElevatedButton`.

The number of views StatefulWidget fetches the count from a remote cloud-based database, and while actually fetching, displays a `CircularProgressIndicator`.

This widget is part of the HUD.

Why does it fetches the database again when I toggle the HUD? And what to do to keep the counter into memory?

This is the main Widget:

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text(widget.ad.title)),
        body: Stack(
          children: [
            GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  if (_displayHud.value == false) {
                    _displayHud.value = true;
                  }
                },
                // == the background image
                child: _buildBackgroundImage(context)),

            // === The foreground UI
            FutureBuilder(
                future: widget.ad.getOwnerUser,
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                    return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                  }

                  final owner = snapshot.data!;

                  return ValueListenableBuilder(
                      valueListenable: _displayHud,
                      builder: (context, value, child) {
                        return Visibility(
                          visible: _displayHud.value,
                          replacement: Align(
                              alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                              child: ElevatedButton(
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    if (_displayHud.value == false) {
                                      _displayHud.value = true;
                                    }
                                  },
                                  child: const Icon(
                                    Icons.fullscreen_exit,
                                  ))),
                          child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                              child: _buildForegroundUi(context,
                                  watchingUser: widget.watchingUser,
                                  owner: owner)),
                        );
                      });
                })
          ],
        ));
  }
```

And here is the count Widget:

```dart
/// A widget that display a coun from a future
class _CounterWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  /// The icon to display
  final IconData iconData;

  /// The future that fetches the count
  final Future<int> getCount;

  /// The press callback
  final void Function()? onPressed;

  const _CounterWidget(
      {required this.iconData, required this.getCount, this.onPressed});

  @override
  State<_CounterWidget> createState() => _CounterWidgetState();
}

class _CounterWidgetState extends State<_CounterWidget> {
  int? _value;
  Exception? _error;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _asyncInitState();
    super.initState();
  }

  void _asyncInitState() async {
    widget.getCount.then((value) {
      if (!mounted) return;
      setState(() {
        _value = value;
      });
    }).catchError((e) {
      if (!mounted) return;
      setState(() {
        _error = e;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const viewerIconColor = Colors.white;
    final viewerTextStyle =
        Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption?.copyWith(color: Colors.white);

    final countWidget = _error != null
        ? const Icon(Icons.error)
        : _value == null
            ? const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
            : Text("$_value", style: viewerTextStyle);

    // === Likes
    if (widget.onPressed == null) {
      return Column(children: [
        Icon(widget.iconData, color: viewerIconColor),
        countWidget
      ]);
    }

    return ElevatedButton(
        style: ButtonStyle(
            shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
          //side: BorderSide(color: Colors.red)
        ))),
        onPressed: widget.onPressed,
        child: Column(children: [Icon(widget.iconData), countWidget]));
  }
}
```

Comment: can you include more about `widget.ad.getOwnerUser` a sample full widget might be better

Answer (score 0):

i've faced this similar issue before. you can see this guy explain with `StreamBuilder`. since this its a video, i'll cut a clip. you can see here:

- problem : https://youtube.com/clip/UgkxU3QOcatZOh1bSRe3KwEEValakNU5josE
- solution: https://youtube.com/clip/UgkxME0hQM6r0bXzFB43nAi5kZCKt1DV0IMn

in summary, you can assign your future function as `state` variable.

```
class _YourClassWidgetState extends State<YourClass> {
final _futureFunc =  widget.ad.getOwnerUser(); // declare as state variable
....
     // === The foreground UI
     FutureBuilder(
         future: _futureFunc,
```

*note: i use `setState()` to update my UI, and since you are using `ValueNotifier()` i dont know it will same behaviour. You may try it on your side.*

but my hypothesis it will same. because updating `ValueListenableBuilder` which also update the `FutureBuilder` *cmiiw